# Isomorphism $f: (M_1 \otimes N_1) \otimes (M_2 \otimes N_2) \to (M_1\otimes M_2) \otimes (N_1 \otimes N_2) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Consider the bimodules ${}_A(M_1)_B, {}_B(M_2)_C, {}_D(N_1)_E$ and ${}_E(N_2)_F$ over $k$-algebras where $k$ is a field. I want to show that there exists an isomorphism

$$ f: (M_1 \otimes_k N_1) \otimes_{B\otimes E} (M_2 \otimes_k N_2) \xrightarrow{\cong} (M_1\otimes_B M_2) \otimes_k (N_1 \otimes_E N_2). $$

Constructing this using the universal property seems to be a bit tricky. Thus I have defined 
$$f((m_1 \otimes_k n_1) \otimes_{B\otimes E} (m_2 \otimes_k n_2)) = (m_1\otimes_B m_2) \otimes_k (n_1 \otimes_E n_2)$$
and extended linearly. How do I show that this map is well-defined?

Answer (score 1):

Since $k$-linearity is automatic, what you have to show is that your map is $(B\otimes_k E)$-balanced, meaning that if $b\in B$ and $e\in E$ then
$$ f((m_1b\otimes n_1e)\otimes (m_2\otimes n_2)) = f((m_1\otimes n_1)\otimes (bm_2\otimes en_2)),$$
which becomes
$$ (m_1b\otimes m_2)\otimes (n_1e\otimes n_2) = (m_1\otimes bm_2)\otimes (n_1\otimes en_2). $$

Now this follows from the properties of $M_1\otimes_B M_2$ and $N_1\otimes_E N_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you mind elaborate on why $k$-linearity is automatic?